# Web3j call a variable in a smart contract

Tags: java, solidity, smartcontracts, geth, web3-java

I am trying to get the value of a variable in a Smart Contract using solidity, geth and web3j.

The contract HelloWorld is very simple:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.10;
   contract HelloWorld {
   uint256 public counter = 5;
  
   function add() public {  //increases counter by 1
       counter++;
   }
 
   function subtract() public { //decreases counter by 1
       counter--;
   }
   
   function getCounter() public view returns (uint256) {
       return counter;
   }
}
```

web3j does not have a call() function, just only send() which is surprising.

when I try get counter following the web3j instructions:

```
contract.getCounter().send()
```

I get a transaction receipt rather than the value uint256.

Can anybody help?

Thank you

Will

Comment: Web3Js does have a call [method](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.7/web3-eth-contract.html#id26).  
To call your getCounter() method use this syntax : 
`contract.methods.getCounter().call()...`

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify the getCounter() function in the generated HelloWorld.java file.

```
public RemoteCall<Type> getCounter() {
    final Function function = new Function(
            FUNC_GETCOUNTER, 
            Arrays.<Type>asList(), 
            Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Uint>() {}));
    return executeRemoteCallSingleValueReturn(function);
}
```

And to get the value, use the following code :

```
Type message = contract.getCounter().send();
System.out.println(message.getValue());
```